# Devise sign up form displays first name can't be blank even after entering the first name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I have created a User migration with first_name and last_name fields. I also generated the Devise views for User. In the Devise Sign Up form I edited to have the first_name and last name fields. When I try to sign up, when I press on Sign up it shows that first_name and Last_name can't be blank even though those fields are not blank. 
User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email,  presence: true
end
```

User Migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email 
    end
  end
end
```

Devise Sign Up form:

```
[![<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them to the strong params for the devise controller.

You can create your own (Which extend Devise) and then:

```
 class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 private

 def sign_up_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
   :password_confirmation)
 end

 def account_update_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, 
   :password_confirmation, :current_password)
 end
 end
```

[Here's a good guide](http://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html)

Good luck!